Every simple module isomorphic to a minimal left ideal when the algebra is Artinian
Let $A$ be an Artinian algebra. Is every simple $A$-module $M$ isomorphic to a minimal left ideal of $A$?
My work:
If there exists a minimal left ideal $N$ such that $NM=M$, then there is a nonzero map $\phi_m: N \to M$ via $\phi_n(m)=nm$. By the simplicity of $M$, $\text{im}(\phi_m)=M$. Hence, $\ker(\phi_m)=\{0\}$ by the simplicity of $N$. Consequently, $N \cong M$.
Now, the question is if such $N$ exists. We know $$AM=M, \ \ \ (I)$$ and it is easy to show that $$ N \not \cong M \Rightarrow NM=0\ \ \text{for every minimal left ideal $N$}. \ \ \ (II)$$ I do not know how to show the existence of minimal left ideal $N$ of $A$ that $NM=M$ with (I) and (II). I can only show that with the additional assumption that $A$ is semisimple.

No, it is not true.  A ring with that property is called left Kasch, and not all left Artinian rings are left Kasch.  One example is $T_2(F_2)$, the $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrices over the field of two elements.
Give it a try finding how this finite ring works as a counterexample for you.

Does it mean every maximal left ideal in a left Kasch ring is direct summand?

@khashayar No: any Artinian local ring is Kasch, but it only has trivial direct summands, which would not allow any of its minimal or maximal ideals to be summands.
